# How to open Word/Excel file after downloading

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I am using below code to download word/excel files.
How i can open this file automatically after downloading ?

```
private void DownloadFile(byte[] bArray, string mimeType, string KeyPath, bool bForcedownload)
        {
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            if (bForcedownload)
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(KeyPath));
            Response.AppendHeader("content-length", bArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.AppendHeader(@"Pragma", @"no-cache");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bArray);
            FlushSupressReponse();
        }

private void FlushSupressReponse()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 
        }
```

Comment: That looks like you're *uploading* a file (sending a file to a client), not downloading.

Comment: Are you serious ? Are these lines for uploading the file ?  Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(KeyPath));
            Response.AppendHeader("content-length", bArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.AppendHeader(@"Pragma", @"no-cache");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bArray);

Comment: Yes I'm serious. That's ASP.NET code that is responding to a request from a browser. Did you write this code yourself, or did you just find it somewhere?

Comment: This is production code which is used to download file...We have UI which runs on browser , user click on filename and file gets downloaded...but user need to click on file to open it but i want to open it automatically once it is downloaded.

Comment: Um... Yes. `Response` is for writing a response (reply), which means you're sending, not receiving, which means you're uploading, not downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment:

> We have UI which runs on browser , user click on filename and file gets downloaded...but user need to click on file to open it but i want to open it automatically once it is downloaded.

You can't. This is entirely the option of the user. You cannot force the user of a website to automatically open a file after downloading.

That is intentionally so, since it would be very easy to distribute viruses that way.

However, you can give your users instructions on how to configure their browser to automatically open files of certain types. For example, in Chrome, after you download a file, there is an arrow beside the file name. Click on that and there is an option to "Automatically Open Files of This Type".

But it's still up to your users to do it.

Comment: This is not true for pdf files as we can use above code to download and open the file in browser..but i know excel/word docs cannot be opened in browser. I am getting byte array and i am using Response.binarywrite()

Comment: Using above code for pdf files i click on file and it opens up in browser

Comment: PDF's are opened *in the browser*, not in an external program (although the user can configure the browser to open them in Adobe Reader instead). That's unique to PDF's.

Comment: For example, see [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en). It points you to an option in Chrome called "Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome". That shows that it specifically treats PDF files differently than everything else.

Comment: There used to be a technology called ActiveX component so that Excel can be loaded inside IE browser.